# How to change this to <%Html.ActionLink%> in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.net mvc could any body help me out how to convert this whole code to use html.Actionlink

```
<div class="MenuItemContainer">
      <a href="/Home">
            <div class="MenuItemContent">
                <div>
                    <img src="/Content/TopMenu/Icons/Home.png" alt="Home" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Home
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom html helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string action, 
        string controller, 
        string imageUrl,
        string alt
    )
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("MenuItemContainer");
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller);
        var itemContent = new TagBuilder("div");
        itemContent.AddCssClass("MenuItemContent");
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.Attributes["src"] = urlHelper.Content(imageUrl);
        img.Attributes["alt"] = alt;
        itemContent.InnerHtml = string.Format(
            "<div>{0}</div><div>{1}</div>", 
            img, 
            htmlHelper.Encode(linkText)
        );
        anchor.InnerHtml = itemContent.ToString();
        div.InnerHtml = anchor.ToString();
        return new HtmlString(div.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
<%= Html.MyActionLink(
     "Hello", 
     "Index", 
     "Home", 
     "~/Content/TopMenu/Icons/Home.png",
     "Home"
) %>
```

Comment: +1 - love, love, love the extensibility of MVC. Great Example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom a custom Html Helper, such as `Helpers.MenuLink("LinkText", "View", "ImagePath/Image.png")`.

Here is a link that explains how to do this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Answer (score 0):

I would make a partial or a display template for this which renders a View Model. Your HtmlHelper extension method would create your view model and call DisplayFor or RenderPartial.

This has the advantage of keeping your template as HTML, this makes it easier to read as opposed to messing around with the tagbuilders.